# Cant find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle

Tags: java, sax, lotus-notes, xpages

I am getting an error and dont know whats the cause of the problem?

```
    java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key connect_not_allowed Nested exception: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key connect_not_allowed org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:291)
com.eoffice.xml.RSSReader.getLimitedRSS(RSSReader.java:25)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(JavaAccessObject.java:321)
com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:175)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTReturn.interpret(ASTReturn.java:49)
com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:261)
com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:185)
com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:171)
com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:175)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTReturn.interpret(ASTReturn.java:49)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:220)
com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:192)
com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:78)
javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:159)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.convertValue(FacesUtil.java:1073)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.OutputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputTextRenderer.java:91)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeEnd(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:153)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:1005)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:809)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:804)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:804)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:804)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:804)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1287)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1225)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:635)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:320)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:355)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:264)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:197)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:193)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:154)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:137)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:86)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:538)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1151)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:803)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:758)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:527)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1135)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:523)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:352)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:304)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:261)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:291)
```

The code is using SAXReader to parse some XML. Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.dominoexperts.com/articles/Misleading-error-for-Java-agent-with-external-Jar) looks like it might be what you're running into.  Google "connect_not_allowed key"